# Generating a dialog box with CheckBoxes when a Checkbox is selected in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I am novice to Ext-js and referring  sencha.com for tutorials. I am trying to modify an existing application build in ext-js 2.2. It has in particular page following options for checkbox.

```
var assetPermissions = [
    { id: 'MF',  name: 'Mutual Funds' },
    { id: 'ETF', name: 'ETFs' },
    { id: 'CE',  name: 'Closed End Funds' },
    { id: 'ST',  name: 'Stocks' },
    { id: 'VA',  name: 'Variable Annuities' },
    { id: 'FI',  name: 'Bonds' },
            { id: 'SMA', name: 'Separately Managed Accounts'  },
    { id: 'MO',  name: 'Models' },
    { id: 'MM',  name: 'Managed Models' },
    { id: 'UD',  name: 'User Defined' },
    { id: 'I:MD',  name: 'Model Dashboard' },
    { id: 'I:SC',  name: 'Screener' },
    { id: 'CUAS',  name: 'Create Custom Assets & Folders' },
            { id: 'OA', name: 'Other Assets'}
];
```

Now I want that when a user selects the Other Assets option in the check box and another check box should be prompted something like this.

```
Name                         Select
ABC
XYZ 
                Save | Cancel
```

I also want a Save and Cancel button for that dialog box and changes made to it are saved.

So can any one suggest how to do this in ExtJs. Thanks.